# What does Mattingly give Parker?

Tags: leverage

Near the end of the Girls' Night Out Job in *Leverage* (Season 4, Episode 13), Craig Mattingly pulls Parker aside, telling her "I've got something for you." I didn't see any hints in the remainder of the episode or in Boys' Night Out Job what it was he gave her. So, what was it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The briefcases. Right after the cut back to the bar, you see Parker with both briefcases that half the episode followed.

[image: Suitcase Screenshot]

Symbolizes Mattingly taking Parker's advice and following Parker's and the entire scoobies' Robin Hood routine.

Comment: @cinemate nice find on the screenshot. I couldn't find a copy of the episode online.

Comment: I own the series. Just had to know where to look. :)